# pushing to one repository makes changes in another - why?

Tags: git

I have three repositories: `repo1`, `repo2`, `repo3`. Both `repo1` and `repo3` have `repo2` configured as a remote repository. `repo2` and `repo3` are on the same remote server, while `repo1` is local repository. Whenever I push to `repo2` from the local `repo1` repository, and go to the `repo3` and execute `git status`, I see files in the commit marked as `modified`. How come `repo3` is affected if I push to `repo2`?

Comment: Is there any hook? (.git/hooks to see the hooks, there also are examples in this directory.)

Comment: You're right, there is a `post-receive` hook. Thanks!